# String.Split Method optimize way in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, split

I have a string `xxx1-0.1/1 yyy,ccc1,1`. I used split and substring. All i want to get is the `0.1/1` only. Is there any optimize way to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If it's always the same position in string I would just pull positions 5 thru 9

Comment: no its a dynamic value **xxx1** can be increase but **yyy** is constant value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use more than one string split chars. then if the position and format is always the same then this will work.

```
Dim s As String = "xxx1-0.1/1 yyy,ccc1,1"
Dim ans = s.Split(New Char() {"-"c, " "c})(1)
MessageBox.Show(ans)
```

Lets make it a function:

```
Private Function getMySpecialValue(input As String) As String
  Return input.Split(New Char() {"-"c, " "c})(1)
End Function
```

Comment: thank you.. it works but i will try more examples because value is dynamic. Although thank you for your quick response.

Comment: Well as long as the `-` and the space are always in the same place it will.